# After using DirectoryEntry all connections from server use the same (last) username

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have a asp.Net application that asks for login and then validates credentials against the domain controller using DirectoryEntry(path,user,password, Secure) and it works correctly.

```
using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, user, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
    try
    {
        string name = de.Name;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
....
        catch (Exception ex0)
        {
            strErr = ex0.Message;
            LoggerHandler.LogError(strErr);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the code there are calls to an external API but not all users have internet access.

```
  var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

  var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

  var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The problem is that when a user is already logged in and tries to execute the api the firewall sees the last user that logged in the application in another computer and not the user that is logged in his computer.

I tried everything that I could remember and can't understand what is happening.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts from your code and show us what have you tried so far

Comment: I hope that the wording is better and is better understandable of what I'm encountering.